I want to make the end/cap of my curve jagged
Hoping to get a jagged effect procedurally going on the end of my curve here as I animate it 'trimming'. I could do this with a noise and a gradient node in shadering but I'd like to sim it in geo nodes.

I tried getting it to work with proximity to an empty (hence that empty in shot) but couldn't get it to work. My thinking was to scale and transform faces closest to the empty. But I'm open to any solution really.
Here is an example of the kinda edge I'd like:

The desired effect is a vine having been ripped out and disintegrating as it unwraps itself from this castle wall.
Thanks in advance.
Here's my current set up:


Here is one way to achieve that. The steps are as follow :

Create low-poly version of the tube
Move the first ring to achieve jagged effect
Apply Subdiv modifier

Base mesh
So first thing, let's generate a low-poly version of the tube. The motivation is that we only have to move the very first ring, and we have room before reaching the second ring.

And here is the same image with the 1st ring highlighted orange, and the 2nd ring highlighted blue :

We only have room until the 2nd ring.
Select 1st ring
The first ring is identifiable by the index : if the resolution of the profile curve is 12, then the first ring is vertices with index 0 to 11. This gives us the following selection :

Move ring vertices
To move the vertices along the tangent, we can Capture Attribute the tangent of the initial curve, and use it as a direction vector for a Set Position node. Basically :

We sample a Noise Texture (so in a [0,1] interval)
We map this interval to a custom [-a,a] so that the vertices are displaced around the initial position (otherwise there is an offset). Note that the a is the amplitude of the jagged effect, controlled in my setup by the Jagged Factor input of the modifier.
We scale the tangent vector with this texture


The danger here is to set an amplitude too high compared to the resolution of the curve and get artifacts :

Subdiv modifier
With the subdiv modifier we get :

If we want to increase the details of the jagged effect, we can :

Increase the Scale of the Noise Texture
Increase the Profile Resolution input of the modifier


Full setup and blend file
Here is the full setup followed by the blend file :


